# Python and MacOSX Automator

Tags: python, macos, automator

I wrote a python program I want to run from a right-click Mac Automator script on my MacBook.  However, I get a permission error I don't know how to work with.  The script runs a bash command, which runs a python program:

`/Users/johncole/Desktop/DALL-E/scripting/Dollybot/openai202211/bin/python /Users/johncole/Desktop/DALL-E/scripting/dalle-right_click/right-click-run-expand_picture.py "\""$1""\"`

[image]

When I run this script, using the play button in Automator, no problem.

[image]

When i try to run this script on a file in the directory, I get an error, I think a permission error:
[image]

`The action “Run Shell Script” encountered an error: “Exception ignored error evaluating path:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 353, in 
PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
Fatal Python error: error evaluating path
Python runtime state: core initialized

Current thread 0x000000011426c600 (most recent call first):
”`

The only thing I can think of is that there's a permission issue with the instance of python I'm calling (which is within a virtual environment).  These are all set I think correctly to be called:

[image]

And the python program also has the correct permissions.

[image]

I've tried changing the permissions of the file "chmod +x" and I've also inserted a small line to echo a value into a troubleshooting script, to make sure Automator has permissions to manipulate files in the directory.

Comment: to recreate this , pls share some reproducible code of `right-click-run-expand_picture.py`

Answer (score 1):

After another 24 hours of debugging, the answer [was in this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/342898/grant-full-disk-access-to-workflows-run-via-the-services-menu).  There was a great comment "I can't believe I have to add Finder to Full Disk Access, but I did, and it works!" and . . . that solved the problem.  All the problems.  Just give Finder permissions for Full Disk Access and you're done.

Comment: This is so ridiculous. After encountering the same issue and going through multiple Google results this looks like the "solution." I find it absurd there isn't a better way to handle this—or at least give a helpful message when it's encountered.